# What's wrong with that JPA query, need to find a user by specific name

Tags: java, jpa

I have a method that search a name, when the user passes a parameter.
Now I need a method to tell me what's the employee's role in the company

The idea is to take this data and insert into a combobox.

This is the method that i used to find the names passes by parameter:

```
public List<User> findbyName(String name) { 
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    String sql = "select u from User u where UPPER(u.name) like UPPER ('" + name + "%')";
    List<User> u = null;
    try {
        u = (List<User> ) em.createQuery(sql).getResultList();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        return null;          
    }
    return u;
}
```

And here is that method that im trying to do:

```
public List<User>  findbyRole(){
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
            String sql = "select u from User u where UPPER(u.role) like (journalist)";
            List<User>  u = null;
    try {
        u = (List<User> ) em.createQuery(sql).getResultList();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        return null;          
    }
    return u;
}
```

Code to insert into combobox, its right?

```
List <User> list= new UserJpaController().findbyRole();
     for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
      combojournalist.addItem(list.get(i).getCargo());
}
```

Comment: You should not catch an exception without logging the error: `} catch (Exception e) {

        return null;          
    }`. Your query is wrong.

Comment: yeah, a need to see that, but the method "findbyName" is working fine, but the method "findbyRole" returns nothing, and i have one person as journalist.Any idea why?

Comment: Should `journalist` be quoted? And shouldn't it be `JOURNALIST`?

Comment: use prepared statments.

Comment: and the SQL invoked is what? you have debugged it haven't you?

Comment: In your findByName method you should use a named query with a parameter for the username to prevent sql-injection. In findByRole you should use a named query as well. But fix it: what does journalist mean? Is it a parameter, a constant, an entity ...?,

Comment: Journalists is a  degree of a person, and i only want to show in the combobox, people with that degree, that's the reason a need the method. The database has several people with different types of degree, but I just want show those with journalists graduation. In findByRole i only want to show to the user the name of the people who are journalists, so i think i don't a parameter passes by user, im wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a literal string `journalist` in your query, you either need to put it into quotes, or pass it as parameter. Otherwise JPA would think that `journalist` is an alias, but such alias is not defined in the query.

So your query should be like this (see quotes around journalist):

```
select u from User u where UPPER(u.role) like ('journalist')
```

or if you use parameters, which is always a better option:

```
String sql = "select u from User u where UPPER(u.role) like (:role)";
List<User>  u = em.createQuery(sql, User.class)
         .setParameter("role", "journalist")
         .getResultList();
```

Comment: If you do not use wildcards in your query, you could also us `=` instead of `like`, like this: UPPER(u.role) = :role

Comment: Thx Ondre, its working now. but i didn't understand how the parameter is working in your code, can you tell me how ? I never used that way

Comment: In JPQL, you may use parameters, which are like variables. You need to prefix such variable with colon (:), so that JPA knows it's a named parameter. You then set the value of the parameter using `query.setParameter`. In this way, JPA makes sure, that parameter's value does not get mixed with other JPQL code, even if it's value contains dangerous characters.

Comment: For more info about parameters, check out this documentation: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter